reference request: conditions for pointwise and operator-norm convergence of kernel projections
At a very high level, I’m interested in the following question. Suppose $X$ is a (separable) Hilbert space, and $T_n : X \rightarrow X$ is a sequence of finite rank self-adjoint maps that converges (either pointwise or in the operator norm) to a self-adjoint map $T: X \rightarrow X$. Let $P_n$ denote the orthogonal projection onto the kernel of $T_n$, and similarly $P$ the orthogonal projection onto the kernel of $T$. Under what conditions does $P_n \rightarrow P$, either pointwise or in the operator norm?
My motivation for asking this comes from showing convergence for finite rank approximations to $T$ via a variety of sampling procedures on increasing subspaces of $X$. I am particularly interested in the convergence of the kernel projections because I ultimately want to use these finite rank approximations to approximate the dynamics $\dot{x} = - Tx$. My problem is suitably flexible that I’m happy to assume $||T_n - T||_{\text{op}} \rightarrow 0$, and consequently that $T$ is compact, if needed.
I have scoured MO and other sources, and found some results, none of which seem like they apply to my situation. In particular, if $T$ has finite dimensional kernel, then this convergence is easy. However in my situation, the kernel of $T$ will generally be infinite dimensional, so I am unable to make this assumption. I also have found a rich theory of spectral approximation which seems relevant, but I’m not seeing the right results. If anyone has any reference suggestions, I’d appreciate it.

I think the results that you can find in the standard books (such as Reed-Simon or Weidmann) on this topic, which you allude to at the end, should give you a good impression of what is true here, and presumably this will be completely useless for your purposes. For example, if $T_n=Q_n/n$, with $Q_n$ being the projection on $\ell^2(-n, \ldots , n)$ in $\ell^2(\mathbb Z)$, then $T_n\to 0$ in norm, but $P_n=1-Q_n$ does not converge to $P=1$, not even strongly. (In fact, $P_n$ projects onto smaller spaces as $n$ increases, so moves in the "wrong" direction.)

Yeah I’ve been looking through the standard literature. This is a very nice example of the difficulty I’m facing, and will make for a good explanatory tool for why this is challenging. I think I might have something when $0$ is an isolated point in the spectrum of $T$, but I’m not sure. Will update.

The lemma in my answer here may be somewhat useful to you. It shows, in particular, that if $T_n$ is a sequence of self-adjoint operators converging pointwise (usually called converging strongly in operator theory, as it is convergence under the strong operator topology) to $1$, then $P_n \to 0 = P$ strongly. (You can also deduce this when $T$ is just assumed invertible, instead of actually $1$.)
